# Preventing to stack clicks with .unbind and setTimeOut, doesn't work on mobile

Tags: click, touch, settimeout, unbind

i have this issue where i wanted to prevent the user to start clicking the hamburger menu and making it go crazy by using unbind and setTimeOut.

It works perfectly on desktop, but not on mobile. I guess i have to add somewhere the touch event, but cannot figure out how...

Here is the code:

```
var click = function() {
$("#pf-mobile-menu-toggler").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        flag = $this.data("clickflag") || false;
    if (!flag) {
        $( ".pf-mobile-menu-wrap" ).removeClass( "pf-invisible" );
        $( ".pf-mobile-menu-wrap li" ).velocity( 'transition.slideLeftBigIn', { easing: 'easeOutQuint', stagger: 100, duration: 200 });
        // Unbind the event
        $('#pf-mobile-menu-toggler').unbind();
        // Call the function 
        setTimeout(function() {
            click();
        }, 420);
    } else {
        $( ".pf-mobile-menu-wrap li" ).velocity( 'transition.slideLeftBigOut', { easing: 'easeOutQuint', stagger: 100, duration: 200 });
        $( ".pf-mobile-menu-wrap" ).addClass( "pf-invisible" );
        // Unbind the event
        $('#pf-mobile-menu-toggler').unbind();
        // Call the function 
        setTimeout(function() {
            click();
        }, 420);
    }
    $this.data("clickflag", !flag);
});
};
click();
```

You can also see the web running at: [www.jairoperez.net](http://www.jairoperez.net)

I'm super new myself with JQuery.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the record: 
Just found out that i had a problem with the timing, the unbind was reseted before the animation ends, so i gave it more time.

```
$('#pf-mobile-menu-toggler').unbind();
// Call the function 
setTimeout(function() {
click();
}, 1000);
```